# Swipe tab items automatically in every 5 seconds

Tags: android, timer, android-tablayout

I have created a tab control in my android application with 3 tab items.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        >
</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

By the help of a `PagerAdapter`, its working fine as expected. But now, I wanted to make it automatically. That is, in every 5 seconds, the tab should swipe automatically to the next. It will continue up-to the user touch on the screen. How can I add this timing functionality in my application?

My `PagerAdapter` class is,

```
public class PagerAdapter  extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{
    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment frag=null;
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                frag=new GameFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                frag=new MovieFragment();
                break;
            case 2:
                frag=new StudyFragment();
                break;
        }
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        String title=" ";
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                title="Game";
                break;
            case 1:
                title="Movie";
                break;
            case 2:
                title="Study";
                break;
        }

        return title;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you know the index of the tab you want to select ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this to auto swipe tabs :

```
int NUM_PAGES = 3;
int currentPage = 0;
boolean touched = false;
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable update;
private void startPagerAutoSwipe() {
    update = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if(!touched){
                if (currentPage == NUM_PAGES) {
                    currentPage = 0;
                }
                pager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
            }
        }
    };
    Timer swipeTimer = new Timer();
    swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(update);
        }
    }, 5000, 5000);
}
```

to stop auto swipe while one of the fragments is tapped you can use the `onTouchListener` for your layouts :

```
layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touched = true;
                return true;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touched = false;
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: You can also use the 'postDelayed' method of the Handler. Override its 'handleMessage' method to do the swipe and also post a new delayed message in there to itself. That way you could get rid of the Timer and the Runnable.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for taking time to answer my question. If I touch on the screen to do something on that view, it is not stopping the auto swiping.

Comment: oh didn't understand that you mean this by *It will continue up-to the user touch on the screen*

Comment: you can set a `onTouchListener` for you layouts and use a `boolean` to track touch events using `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` and `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` and that `boolean` can be used to enable/disable the auto swipe.